# Exporting data and graphs from a python GUI into a single file

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, matplotlib

I have made a GUI with qt designer and python. In this GUI i have multiple tabs. In some tabs i display a matplotlib widget and in some tabs i display a textedit. After pressing a button lines will be plotted in the matplotlib widgets and in the textedit some data will be displayed. How can i get these matplotlib graphs and the data from the textedits into one file after pressing an 'export' button?

Comment: By "file" do you mean a single image?

Comment: No, it can be for example an excel file, or an image. As long as it is one file

Comment: An image would be far less complicated than a spreadsheet file since that would involve another API.  If an image really is ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify many constraints, but if one big honking image is sufficient, you can take snapshots of the relevant widgets using [Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) or [Qt4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWidget) and just tile them into gigantic image:

After calling `QWidget::grab` or `Pixmap::grabWidget`, find the most reasonable layout for all the widgets and calculate the total size.  Then create one gigantic `QPixmap` and render them via [QPainter::drawPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPixmap-9) to the appropriate coordinates into the combined image.

Of course, this seems pretty ugly and questionable to me, but I'm not one to second-guess what you want to do either... just know that I realize this is kind of icky.